# Error executing dynamic sql query in phpmyadmin(error : #1046)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dynamic-sql

I trying to run my dynamic query in PhpMyAdmin but mysql display this:

> ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS nvarchar(max) DECLARE
>   @AgrColumns AS nvarchar(max)' at line 1

This is my query :

```
DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @AgrColumns AS nvarchar(max)

--Get distinct values of the Column 
SELECT @AgrColumns = ISNULL(@AgrColumns + ',', '') + 'SUM(CASE WHEN REASON_NAME = ''' + REASON_NAME + ''' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(REASON_NAME)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT REASON_NAME FROM Reason) AS Reasons

--Prepare the query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicQuery =
N'SELECT ' + @AgrColumns + ' FROM 
(
    SELECT r.REASON_NAME, SUM(CASE WHEN c.ID is null OR rg.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS cnt 
    FROM Reason r
    LEFT JOIN Chat c ON (c.REASON_ID = r.ID)
    LEFT JOIN Reason_Group rg ON (r.REASON_GROUP_ID = rg.ID)
    GROUP BY REASON_NAME
) inn'

--Execute the Dynamic Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery
```

First table Chat:

```
ID    REASON_ID    DEPARTMENT_ID    
 1      46           1
 2      46           1
 3      50           1
 4      50           2
 5      100          1 
 6      100          2
```

Second table Reason:

```
ID    REASON_NAME     REASON_GROUP_ID
46    Reason1         1
50    Reason2         1
100   Reason3         2
101   Reason4         2
105   Reqson5         3
```

Third table Reason_Group :

```
ID    NAME
1     Group1
2     Group2
3     Group3
```

How can i solve the problem ?
PhpMyAdmin Version: 4.2.11

Comment: Semicolons. You need semicolons.

Comment: all the semicolons are true @Darwin von Corax

Comment: There are no statement delimiters in your code. You need a semicolon (or whatever the current delimiter is) to mark the end of each statement.

Answer (score 1):

Declare can only appear in a [begin ... end block](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) that forms a compund statement block. If you do not want to use a stored program, then use user defined variables with [set statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

However, the code you try to execute seems to be ms sql and not mysql, so you need to seriously rewrite the whole code before you can run it in mysql environment.

Comment: how can i convert it to mysql query? @shadow